# Permanently remove a div ( also from view source) by jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

is that possible to remove a div by jquery? the condition is it should also remove from view source. I used below code its not working

```
<div>lorem ibsum dolor </div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>  
   $(document).ready(function () {
      $("div").remove();
   });
</script>
```

Comment: It is not possible.

Comment: Do you mean something like this? - ```$("div").click(() => {$("div").remove()});```

Comment: Iirc, most(?) browsers view-source is its own request, so won't be influenced by clicking around in another tab

Comment: You can't remove, or change in any other way the "_View Source_" page from client-side. It is the original version of the page loaded from the server.

Comment: I'm assuming that he *means* when you press f12? ...Aka the *"Elements"* tab.

Comment: I guess you could just delete the div form your code

Comment: @JO3-W3B-D3V I doub't that, since the DevTools would "work", and the question wouldn't be needed.

Comment: When you remove the div also store on the server that it's been removed so when user makes a new request (view source request) it's not rendered on page load.

Comment: @Teemu Good point... In that case the only valid solution would be to use some framework that manages UI stuff on the back end or something along those lines?

Comment: You're doing this at the page load. Why not remove the element from the source file all together? I mean currently nobody can actually never see the div anyway.

Comment: If you want to remove div `from view source` you can try to append div on some event. and hide it after your request is over so it wont show to `view source`

Comment: Why is this tagged with `php`?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that the way you want it. When using JavaScript / jQuery after the page has loaded, you are working on the client side. This does not change what the server sent to the client.

When using "View source", you are essentially getting the source that the server sent to the client initially. If you want to prevent a client from seeing something the server sent, the only way is to not send it in the first place, i.e. change the server side.

If you are sending the to-be-removed div, for example, to transmit secret settings / a password the client uses for a direct connection to another server: Do not do that. Route the traffic through the first server and let it check the permissions for the client. There might be other / better ways depending on your use-case though.

Answer (score 1):

As many have said in different ways on this question is that basically this cannot be done as you are trying to do it.  A simple rule to note is that anything sent to the client is accessible by the client. Be that in the original code from the server (View Source) or via inspecting the DOM (for any dynamic changes).

As to your View Source question one possible way to address this is of course to not put that div in your code (either in HTML or in JavaScript).  Your code could make a server call via AJAX to retrieve the div part you wish to insert after page loads and assign to an object/variable.    This will make it all DOM then so it would only be visible while part of the DOM.   When removed via jQuery / Javascript it would no longer be visible in the DOM and since it was never part of the initial page loaded from the server it will not be visible there as well.

The only question you would really have then would be if this effort is worth making to achieve your end goal.

Comment: thanx @bob tate

Comment: Be aware that loading anything via AJAX still leaves a trace in the Network tab in the development tools and shows the content you load.

Comment: Yes, that is correct hence my initial warning that  a simple rule to note is that anything sent to the client is accessible by the client.